# what does this struct do?

Tags: c, linux

i came across a struct in "linux/list.h" such as shown below. I don't completely understand it or how it can be used? It seems to be some sort of marker structure as it declare any variable to contain any information, other than empty itself. How would you use it?

```
struct list_head {
  struct list_head *next, *prev;
  };
```

Comment: Look up "double linked list"

Comment: Also "intrusive list". Basically, something (either a structure representing the whole list or the code that manipulates the list) knows what offset the list node is from the start of the object that's being put on a list. So given a node, you access the data by subtracting that offset.

Comment: You may want to read [this page](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) on why and how of `list_head`. Or [this page](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-11-sect-5). Basically, search `list_head` on google.

Comment: @Shahbaz +1 for the links, ty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a linked list without data elements seems strange. But, did you try searching for usages of the struct in other headers?

I am guessing they will use this struct in other structures which need a linked list, like say  the buffer free list etc. You will find the data elements there.

Comment: This is the key: it's designed to be put inside a larger structure that contains the node data.

Comment: It's designed to be used with the Linux `container_of()` macro.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I would say being able to use container_of is a consequence of having that struct, and not the reason for having the struct.

Comment: Being able to use the struct is also a consequence of `container_of()`.  "Reason" is such an overloaded term, the "purpose" of `container_of()` is to work with structs like these, and it "causes" structs like these to be usable.  The two are designed to work together.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: A simple enough test, without any need to add confusion and quotes to reasonable statements :-) Which came first? The struct or container_of? Anyway, you are probably right.

Answer (score 0):

It's called linked list. Look at this (especially double linked list) at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Answer (score 0):

This is typical linked list structure. It is a node which holds pointers to neighboring nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a cursor, which pointed to a linked list and tells your position.
This is useful with single-linked-list.